# Why DOM cannot be used in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've seen this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGSHfObcVf4 to understand how javascript works. Around 16:00 the instructor mentions that a runtime environment provides a web API (on top of the processing engine) that has DOM.

Therefore, if Nodejs is a javascript runtime environment, how come DOM cannot be accessed / used in it?

Comment: What exactly would you be trying to do in NodeJS that would require a DOM? I think you have _server-side_ and _client-side_ mixed up

Comment: The DOM is a browser API

Comment: This question needs to be asked clearer.  What are you trying to do?  There are libraries to simulate a DOM in NodeJS.

Comment: You're right, I did confuse client-side with server-side (was building a web application for the first time and hit a brick wall when trying to create modals in nodejs by using `document`). As a follow-up, if nodejs provides front-end functionality then the separation would be obsolete, or is it more complicated (otherwise I'd assume that such a platform should already exist)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is hosted in some *context*. The common context and the one most developers are familiar with is that their Javascript is hosted in a *Browser Context*. The browser is what provides the DOM API.

Nodejs is an independent context, not within a browser, and is most often used in a server context. Nodejs provides other baseline facilities but, since it's *not* a browser, it doesn't provide the DOM api.

Theoretically nodejs or an add-on *could* provide the DOM api and you could simulate a browser, but that's not its normal environment.

Answer (score 3):

Nodejs is a JS runtime environment designed to allow JavaScript to run outside of the browser. It's a backend technology.

Because it runs outside of the browser, there is no DOM. Therefore, Nodejs does not have access to it.